# org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create a sink for writing table 'default_catalog.default_database.hTable'

Tags: hbase, apache-flink, version, flink-sql, pyflink

I am trying to connect Flink 1.14.4 with HBase version 2.2.14;
I am added Hbase SQL connector jar flink-sql-connector-hbase-2.2-1.15.2.jar , but for version 2.2.x becauce it is the last version of jar.

but I got the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1.executeSql.
: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create a sink for writing table 'default_catalog.default_database.hTable'.

Table options are:

'connector'='hbase-2.2'
'table-name'='test'
'zookeeper.quorum'='127.0.0.1:2181'
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createTableSink(FactoryUtil.java:184)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.getTableSink(PlannerBase.scala:388)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translateToRel(PlannerBase.scala:222)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase$$anonfun$1.apply(PlannerBase.scala:182)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase$$anonfun$1.apply(PlannerBase.scala:182)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:182)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1665)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:752)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:872)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeSql(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:742)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory$Context.getPhysicalRowDataType()Lorg/apache/flink/table/types/DataType;
        at org.apache.flink.connector.hbase2.HBase2DynamicTableFactory.createDynamicTableSink(HBase2DynamicTableFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createTableSink(FactoryUtil.java:181)
        ... 28 more
```

My hbase table is defined:

```
sink_ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE hTable (
            datemin STRING,
            family2 ROW<datemax STRING>,
            family3 ROW<channel_title STRING, channel_id STRING>,
            PRIMARY KEY (datemin) NOT ENFORCED
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'hbase-2.2',
          'table-name' = 'test',
          'zookeeper.quorum' = '127.0.0.1:2181'
        )
        """
```

T created a view to select data for elements and to insert them in hTable:

```
table_env.create_temporary_view('table_api_table', table)
table_env.execute_sql("""
    INSERT INTO hTable
        SELECT
            datemin,
            ROW(datemax),
            ROW(channel_title, channel_id)
        FROM table_api_table
""").wait()
```

I see that Flink 1.14 dont't support Hbase [image]

So do I have to change hbase version?

Comment: I changed the hbase version but I still have the same issue :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182290/flink-hbase-connector-write-data-in-hbase-sink-table-unable-to-create-a-sink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's working !!
I fixed this issue by doing the following:

I edited hbase-env.sh :

```
# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/hbase/conf
```

I edited hbase-site.xml, so I added the following propertie:

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

Then editing the connector jar , indeed I unpackaged the jar and then I edited hbase-default.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Set to true to skip the 'hbase.defaults.for.version' check.
        Setting this to true can be useful in contexts other than
        the other side of a maven generation; i.e. running in an
        IDE.  You'll want to set this boolean to true to avoid
        seeing the RuntimeException complaint: "hbase-default.xml file
        seems to be for and old version of HBase (\${hbase.version}), this
        version is X.X.X-SNAPSHOT"</description>
</property>
```

and finally, moving the jar in flink lib folder (it's better than :

```
table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("pipeline.jars","file:///home/hadoop/hbase/conf/flink-sql-connector-hbase-2.2_2.11-1.14.4.jar")
```

)

this articles helped me a lot:
https://www.cnblogs.com/panfeng412/archive/2012/07/22/hbase-exception-hbase-default-xml-file-seems-to-be-for-and-old-version-of-hbase.html

https://blog.csdn.net/bokzmm/article/details/119882885

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix and match JARs from different Flink versions.

- If you're using Flink 1.14, you'll need to use the JARs that are available via https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/table/hbase/
- If you're using Flink 1.15, you'll need to use the JARs that are available via https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/hbase/

The screenshot that you're referring to mentions that HBase is supported, so I don't understand why you're mentioning that that Flink 1.14 doesn't support HBase.

Comment: I mean Flink don't support my version of Hbase which is 2.4.14

Comment: my quistion is : does the connector Jar of hbase version 2.2  work with version 2.4

Comment: Flink doesn't yet support 2.4. There are plans to update this (see https://lists.apache.org/thread/x7l2gj8g93r4v6x6953cyt6jrs8c4r1b) but so far that's just a proposal.

Comment: I changed the hbase version to 2.2.0 but I sill have the same problem :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182290/flink-hbase-connector-write-data-in-hbase-sink-table-unable-to-create-a-sink

Comment: I got a new error  when I changed the jar: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml file seems to be for an older version of HBase (1.4.8), this version is 2.2.3

Comment: That error message is pretty descriptive I would say. You're using a wrong version of hbase-default.xml for your HBase connector.