# Flink Hbase connector: write data in Hbase sink table : Unable to create a sink for writing table

Tags: jar, bigdata, hbase, apache-flink, pyflink

I want to write data in hbase sink table, I have Hbase version 2.2.0 which is compatible flink version 1.14.4
I defined the sink hbase table as follows:

```
sink_ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE hTable (
            datemin STRING,
            family2 ROW<datemax STRING>,
            family3 ROW<channel_title STRING, channel_id STRING>,
            PRIMARY KEY (datemin) NOT ENFORCED
        ) WITH (
          'connector' = 'hbase-2.2',
          'table-name' = 'test',
          'zookeeper.quorum' = '127.0.0.1:2181'
        )
        """
```

And I write data into it with:

```
table_env.execute_sql("""
    INSERT INTO hTable
        SELECT
            datemin,
            ROW(datemax),
            ROW(channel_title, channel_id)
        FROM table_api_table
""")
```

but I got error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1.executeSql.
: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create a sink for writing table 'default_catalog.default_database.hTable'.

Table options are:

'connector'='hbase-2.2'
'table-name'='test'
'zookeeper.quorum'='127.0.0.1:2181'

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory$Context.getPhysicalRowDataType()Lorg/apache/flink/table/types/DataType;
        at org.apache.flink.connector.hbase2.HBase2DynamicTableFactory.createDynamicTableSink(HBase2DynamicTableFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createTableSink(FactoryUtil.java:181)
        ... 28 more
```

btw: I added connector jar

please any help?
what is the cause of this error?

how can I connect flink with hbase

Comment: Which JARs have you added? It appears that you're missing one of the Flink JARs. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/project-configuration/ for how to configure your project.

Comment: I added flink-sql-connector-hbase-2.2-1.15.2.jar

Comment: I am using python Flink API (pyFlink), I want to write processed data in HBase sink table

Comment: Once again you've added a connector version for a different Flink version (1.15.2) instead of the one you've specified in your original question (1.14.4). The same as you've done in your original question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156056/org-apache-flink-table-api-validationexception-unable-to-create-a-sink-for-writ/

Comment: I highly recommend for you to follow the guides for the PyFlink introduction to the Table API https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/python/table/intro_to_table_api/ and the one for PyFlink Dependency Management https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/python/dependency_management/

Comment: eveything is correct about Flink table api and dependencies, the cause of the issue is about hbase-default.xml configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's working !!
I fixed this issue by doing the following:

I edited hbase-env.sh :

```
# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/hbase/conf
```

I edited hbase-site.xml, so I added the following propertie:

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

Then editing the connector jar , indeed I unpackaged the jar and then I edited hbase-default.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Set to true to skip the 'hbase.defaults.for.version' check.
        Setting this to true can be useful in contexts other than
        the other side of a maven generation; i.e. running in an
        IDE.  You'll want to set this boolean to true to avoid
        seeing the RuntimeException complaint: "hbase-default.xml file
        seems to be for and old version of HBase (\${hbase.version}), this
        version is X.X.X-SNAPSHOT"</description>
</property>
```

and finally, moving the jar in flink lib folder (it's better than :

```
table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string("pipeline.jars","file:///home/hadoop/hbase/conf/flink-sql-connector-hbase-2.2_2.11-1.14.4.jar")
```

)

this articles helped me a lot:
https://www.cnblogs.com/panfeng412/archive/2012/07/22/hbase-exception-hbase-default-xml-file-seems-to-be-for-and-old-version-of-hbase.html

https://blog.csdn.net/bokzmm/article/details/119882885